# Где перечислены макросы названий стандартных элементов WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi, macro

Создаю обычное окно через `CreateWindowW( LPCWSTR lpClassName , ... )`, но вместо `L"Button"` напрямую, хочу юзать макрос, как например в этой отсебятине:

```
#define ELEM_BUTTON L"Button"
#define ELEM_COMBOBOX L"ComboBox"
```

По идее где-то в заголовочных файлах WinAPI они уже зашиты да??

Comment: Включите тогда как ответ свою находку, чтобы не путать остальных и вопрос иметь отвеченным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл. В заголовке `"CommCtrl.h"` есть `WC_BUTTONW`, `WC_COMBOBOXEXW` и т.д.